# Generic Hashes as arguments?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to implement a class which accepts a generic payload and then converts it to JSON:

```
require "json"

class Response
  alias Payload = Hash(Symbol | String, String | Bool | Int32 | Int64 | Float32 | Float64 | Nil)
  @payload : Payload

  def initialize(@payload, @method : String = "sendMessage")
  end

  def to_json
    @payload.merge({"method" => @method}).to_json
  end
end

Response.new({
  "chat_id" => update.message.not_nil!.chat.id,
  "text"    => "Crystal is awesome but complicated",
})
```

But I get `instance variable '@payload' of Response must be Hash(String | Symbol, Bool | Float32 | Float64 | Int32 | Int64 | String | Nil), not Hash(String, Int64 | String)` compiler error. How can I overcome this? Does Crystal support generic Hashes? Why it can't convert even if types overlap?

The `Response` is a part of a shard, so I don't know which hashes would be passed as arguments, but `Payload` has to be enough.

Comment: I think that you're probably using Hash wrongly here. It's very different from Ruby where Hash is used as a generic "data bag". In Crystal you'd want to create a custom class or record type instead of using a hash here. The difference is that with Hash, there is no relationship between keys and the types of the values, which makes it very hard to use for this purpouse. If you create a class, each property has it's own type and can be used much easier. Please don't try to program Ruby in Crystal.

Comment: @RX14 I see. I have to write more code than I used to in Ruby. But it gives me better performance and less errors :)

Comment: Yes it's more code but often it's less time in the long run as your bugs are caught in the compiler not at runtime. And when you come back to the code after a few months, it's easier to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Your payload hash is of type `Hash(String, Int32 | String)`:

```
typeof({
  "chat_id" => update.message.not_nil!.chat.id,
  "text"    => "Crystal is awesome but complicated",
}) # => Hash(String, Int32 | String)
```

But the constructor expects a `Hash(Symbol | String, String | Bool | Int32 | Int64 | Float32 | Float64 | Nil)`.
These are diffferent types and cannot be magically casted. You'll need to ensure your payload has the correct type.

One way to do this is to explicitly declare the type of the hash literal:

```
Payload{
  "chat_id" => update.message.not_nil!.chat.id,
  "text"    => "Crystal is awesome but complicated",
}
```

This is of course not great, but depending on your usecase it might be sufficient.

If you want to have a general interface that allows to receive any type of hash, you'll need to cast it to the `Payload` type. This means copying the data into a new hash of that type:

```
def self.new(hash, method : String = "sendMessage")
  payload = Payload.new
  hash.each do |key, value|
    payload[key] = value
  end
  new(payload, method)
end
```

For a real-world example, I am using this approach in [Crinja](https://github.com/straight-shoota/crinja/blob/ce9bb42b765137c02af53930eb6dd6778479687d/src/crinja/runtime/bindings.cr#L43) to convert a number of different type variations to the matching ones.

Comment: It's possible to use `Payload{"chat_id" => update.message.not_nil!.chat.id, "text" => "Crystal is awesome but complicated"}` to shorten the hash literal.

Comment: I always keep forgetting this hash literal syntax... :D Updated the original answer.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer @JohannesMüller